# Using Regression for Causal Analysis on Non-Experimental Data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, panel-data, causality, propensity-scores

I have a small hypothetical dataset(D1) with X unique subjects that contains data on the smoking habits of the subjects, their age, gender, etc. and whether they have cancer or not. Let's assume all subjects did not have cancer.

In another dataset(D2) I have data on 0.5*X subjects from the first study, with the same data recorded as the first time but 5 years apart. Let's assume some of the subjects here have cancer now.

My objective is to perform a **causal analysis** to uncover what caused the cancer after 5 years.

My current approach has involved anonymizing the dataset(removing the subject IDs), merging both datasets to include only those who were present in both surveys, creating a dummy variable for the year in which they were surveyed(coded as *0* for the first contact and *1* if they were involved in the study 5 years later).

I subsequently run a multiple regression analysis based on my hypothesis about the main causes of cancer from available variables in the dataset.

**My questions are**:

1. Is this an approach than can be published? Let's also assume I had no input in the analysis and I only had access to just the results obtained from the method described exactly as above.
2. How can I use propensity score matching in this case?
3. From the regression results I observe that 3 main variables are significant in predicting cancer. Would these variables be my causal factors, and is that a sensible interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I imagine you could publish this if the findings were novel or surprising. Many studies use secondary data sets. If you got the data set from a specific individual or group, they might have requests for how you acknowledge their data collection efforts (e.g., by adding them as co-authors).

2) You cannot. Propensity score matching can tell you the effect of a given cause, but not the causes of observed variability. You are asking a different question than what propensity scores are designed to answer.

3) It's very hard to claim that these are the causal factors. There may be other confounding variables that are the true causes and are just correlated with your predictors. There may also be mediators which provide a better causal explanation. In general, it's challenging to make a valid claim about what the causes of observed variability. You can only say that your factors are associated with variability in cancer survival unless your variable list contains a reasonably exhaustive set of variables and you don't want to include mediating causes in your analysis.

Comment: On answer 2 above, does that mean that in order to use propensity score matching, I would need to take each of my hypothesised "causal" variables in turn and run an analysis to find out how much of the variability in observed output they contribute to?

Comment: Do you offer consultancy services? Would you mind if we spoke briefly? I'm happy to remunerate you for this. Cheers.

Comment: On answer 2, I would not advise that approach. Many of your variables are not suitable for PSM because they are not manipulable (e.g., age/gender). Stick to regression and related techniques for this question. If you find a potential cure for cancer and want to estimate it's effect without randomly assigning, then come back to propensity scores.

I appreciate the offer, but I don't consult. I'm happy to keep answering questions here if you like. Good luck.

Comment: Cheers @Noah. How about using multi-level modelling? Using the MIXED procedure in SPSS, which is still a linear model, wouldn't this allow me to better model both fixed and random effects?

Comment: It would, but that wouldn't necessarily strengthen your case for a causal explanation. It's about which variables you include. The next step is figuring out how to include them (e.g., regression, MLM, SEM, etc.).

Comment: Your issue is really more a theoretical one than a statistical one. Think of it as a skeptic: what argument could I make to denounce your causal explanation? As of now, there are many plausible arguments (some of which I made in my answer). The statistical method you end up using will be relatively inconsequential compared to the theoretical justification you have for the causal relationships you propose.